# Compile a JasperReport file

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

I'm using `JasperReport` to generate a `PDF`. Now I'm using the compiled `.jasper`, file but I want a `backup` in case of error to let `Jasper` recompile the original `JRXML` file.
How can I do this? Is this a best practice?

This is my code:

```
InputStream reportC1 = ReportService.class.getResourceAsStream(JASPER_IN_PACKAGE);
bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportC1, params, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(records));
PdfReader doc = new PdfReader(bytes);
```

Where `JASPER_IN_PACKAGE` is a constant to `.jasper` file.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily compile .jrxml files with

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(sourceFile, targetFile);
```

where `sourceFile` is a `File` to your .jrxml, `targetFile` is the `File` to your to-be-created .jasper file.

And for the "Best Practice": I always deploy only the .jrxml files and compile them if the respective .jasper file is older that the .jrxml file. This allows me to easily edit the source files without having to compile them locally. And it is IMHO also best practice because one should never commit anything which can be reconstructed, especially not binary content.

Comment: Is possible to get directly an InputStream instead to save the file (for example if it is read from a Resource inside a package)?

Comment: Yes, you can directly use an `InputStream` as a source and you also do not need to save the compiled result. Just check out the methods in [JasperCompileManager](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperCompileManager.html)